# How to create a Sitemap for CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp, sitemap

I want to create a sitemap, but I know very little about the usage of Sitemaps. I use CakePHP. There is a lot software on google and guides, but I still want ask anyway, for an easy way to create sitemaps for CakePHP.

I uploaded the website on the server, it doesn't rely on localhost.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's a quick'n'dirty example for you to play with and adjust to your needs:

In your controller:

```
public $components = array('RequestHandler');

public function sitemap()
{
    Configure::write('debug', 0);

    $articles = $this->Article->getSitemapInformation();

    $this->set(compact('articles'));
    $this->RequestHandler->respondAs('xml');
}
```

Your "Article" model:

```
public function getSitemapInformation()
{
    return $this->find('all', array(/* your query here */));
}
```

View:

```
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
    <?php foreach ($articles as $article): ?>
    <url>
        <loc><?php echo Router::url(/* generate the URLs here */); ?></loc>
        <lastmod><?php echo $time->toAtom(/* last update time here */); ?></lastmod>
        <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
    </url>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</urlset>
```

Comment: Remember to add public ´$components = array('RequestHandler');´ in your controller (or AppController.php for app-wide access) for this to work.

Comment: please check my issue where i'm doing wrong and also sitemap.xml blank file?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39099791/display-data-from-database-in-sitemap-xml-using-cakephp-2-0?noredirect=1#comment65552181_39099791

Answer (score 4):

That is a good start, now just add:

`Router::parseExtensions('xml');` to routes.php

From there you want to have a route like:

`Router::connect('/sitemap', array('controller' => 'posts' ....., 'ext' => 'xml'))` that will direct site.com/sitemap.xml to the controller/action where the sitemap is.

create a xml layout with the correct headings, and move the view file to views/posts/xml/file.ctp

Comment: please check my issue where i'm doing wrong and also sitemap.xml blank file?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39099791/display-data-from-database-in-sitemap-xml-using-cakephp-2-0?noredirect=1#comment65552181_39099791

Answer (score 3):

Even better: add `Router::parseExtensions('xml');` to routes.php (without the typo)

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the following steps:

Step 1. Create a layout file sitemap.ctp for XML sitemap view

```
<?php
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
echo '<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">';
echo $this->fetch('content');
echo '</urlset>';
?>
```

Step 2. Create a separate controller for the Sitemap generation:

```
class SitemapsController extends AppController
{
    public function index()
    {
        $this->viewBuilder()->setLayout('sitemap');
        $this->RequestHandler->respondAs('xml');
        
        $postTbl = TableRegistry::getTableLocator()->get('Posts');
        $posts = $postTbl->find()->select(['slug']);
        $this->set('posts', $posts);

        //Get the base URL of your website
        $url = Router::url('/', true);
        $this->set('url', $url);

    }

}
```

Step 3. Create a view file for index action containing XML tags: index.ctp

```
<url>
    <loc><?= $url; ?></loc>
    <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
    <priority>1.0</priority>
</url>
<url>
    <loc><?= $url; ?>contact-us</loc>
    <priority>0.5</priority>
</url>
<url>
    <loc><?= $url; ?>above-us</loc>
    <priority>0.5</priority>
</url>
<url>
    <loc><?= $url; ?>service</loc>
    <priority>0.5</priority>
</url>
<?php foreach($osts as $post){?>
<url>
    <loc><?php echo $url.'blog/'.$post['slug'] ?></loc>
</url>
<?php } ?>
```

Step 4. Add a route for sitemap in routes.php:

```
Router::scope('/', function (RouteBuilder $routes) {
    // Other routes.
    $routes->connect('/sitemap.xml',['controller'=>'Sitemaps','action'=>'index']);
});
```

For the detailed tutorial, you can [visit this tutorial](https://codingkala.blogspot.com/2021/01/how-to-create-xml-sitemap-in-cakephp.html) and learn step by step how to create an XML sitemap in CakePHP.