# Cakephp sitemap for google

Tags: php, cakephp, sitemap

I am trying to make my first sitemap to use with google for the site that I am making. The thing is that all the displayed content is static, all the solutions i found are related with the usage of models. How can I make a sitemap for a Cake site like this? Also, is it possible to do it using the Routes, on `routes.php` file or does it need to be made in a more complex way?

I am using CakePHP 2.4.4.

Comment: what have you tried so far? please show some code. Also: You should always mention the exact cakephp version you are using.

Comment: @mark I don't have anything yet, as I don't know what kind of approach I should have.

Comment: @SunT sounds like you're over complicating things - if you don't have models your site is static. Write a static sitemap, and "that's it".

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create sitemap for cakephp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3789841/how-to-create-sitemap-for-cakephp)

Comment: @AD7six And can that be done using something like `<loc><?php?Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'home', 'action' => 'index'));?></loc>`, or should I use it with the plain URL?

Comment: it can - in what way is writing a static xml file and putting it in your webroot _not_ a solution? Don't do things the hard way just for the sake of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you don't need any dynamic content (from the way you asked your question there is no way of knowing if you do), just create a static

```
sitemap.xml
```

in your /webroot directly
That's it.

Nothing else necessary.
Always keep things as simple as possible.