# Display data from database in sitemap.xml using cakephp 2.0

Tags: php, cakephp, sitemap

I have created a file `sitemap.xml` and stored in app/webroot/ and this is a file I can view from browser like this `example.com/sitemap.xml`. I have created `sitemap function in controller` where I will get data from database and pass to `view/listings/sitemap.ctp`. Also I have added `Router::connect` in app/config/routes.php file.

Problem is that data is not showing in the example.com/sitemap.xml file?

**Listings Controller File:**

```
var $name = 'Listings';
var $components = array('RequestHandler');

public function sitemap(){
       $this->layout='ajax'; 
       $this->RequestHandler->respondAs('xml');
       $listData = $this->Listing-
       >find('all',array('conditions'=>array('Listings.status'=>1)
       ,'order'=> array('Listings.created'=>'Desc')));
       $this->set(compact('listData'));
}
```

**Sitemap.ctp File:**

```
<?php App::uses('CakeTime', 'Utility'); ?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
<url>
    <loc><?php echo $html->link('/',true); ?></loc>
    <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
</url>

<?php foreach ($listData as $list){ ?>
<url>
    <loc><?php echo $html->link(array('controller' => 'listings', 'action' 
     => 'sitemap',$list['listings']['id']),true); ?></loc>
    <lastmod><?php echo $this->Time->toAtom($list['listings']['created']); ?
    ></lastmod>
    <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
</url>
<?php } ?>

</urlset>
```

**Routes.php File:**

```
Router::connect('/sitemap.xml',array('controller' => 'listings', 
'action' => 'sitemap', 'ext'=>'xml'));
Router::parseExtensions('xml');
```

When I try to access /listings/sitemap in the browser it shows an error message:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried removing the cache? http://debuggable.com/posts/cakephp-removecache-shell---remove-your-cache-files-easily:4a277938-977c-43bc-bd83-645c4834cda3

Comment: yes i did in fact i can also get data from database when i try `print_r($listData );` but sitemap.xml showing empty?

Comment: In your controller you set listData, but in sitemap.ctp you trying to loop $listNews  ???

Comment: @Salines i have changed list news to listdata but still blank ?

Comment: move sitemap.ctp to view/listings/xml/sitemap.ctp

Comment: file moved to xml/ but still blank?

Comment: debug($listData); $html->link to $this->Html->link() ...

Comment: @Salines in my application by default ` $html->link`

Comment: please provide solution?

Answer (score 0):

Put your view in a xml sub folder :

```
view/listings/xml/sitemap.ctp
```